# Problems with installing Django with Python3

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, python-3.5

I have installed `virtualenv`

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
```

Then created a new `virtualenv`

`virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.5 venv`

It returned

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.5
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/alexandra/Documents/online-store/venv/bin/python3.5
Also creating executable in /home/alexandra/Documents/online-store/venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
```

Activated it

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Then installed `Django`

```
sudo pip3 install django
```

It installed there (that is what `sudo pip3 install django --upgrade` returned)

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
```

Maybe that's the problem? Because it installed in `python3.4` and not `python3.5`. But how to install `Django` in `python3.5`?

In file `manage.py` there is a path to `python3.5` in this virtualenv.

Then I run

```
python manage.py runserver
```

It returns an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Don't use `sudo` to create the virtual environment; you'll have all kinds of problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using pip to install packages inside the virtual env, do not sudo. It makes packages be installed globally. Simply remove sudo from beginning of the command and it should install it in the venv you are currently working on.

Comment: Thanks! That actually helped!

Answer (score 0):

You installed django into a system python 3.4.

When you ran install command first time without sudo, did it complain about permissions? That should have been your clue that it's not the right `pip`. My guess is `pip3` only exists in system python and not your virtualenv. You can use `which` to find out, but this will work in any case:

```
venv/bin/pip install django
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do `sudo` and just use `pip` for installing all the packages. You have already installed python3 in your virtualenv, so there is no need of using pip3.
Just do e.g. `pip install django`. or for other packages `pip install <package_name>`